# How to add dynamic HTML content (DIV) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need help adding dynamic html on return of data from server side. I'm using ajax/jQuery to handle server-side processing requirements. Currently, the success code section of ajax I can write html elements (see **ajax** below) but this is okay for **demo** page but for real code this is making me write loads of these html rendering in html code.

In the HTML page I have included html code which I want to appear to the user when he clicks the submit button and hide the view (div id) at back. Can I tell JavaScript to add this html code dynamically? From server side I want to just pass the following value under

```
<div id="package-header-message">
            <div class="spacer-vertical"></div>
            <div>Your incident was submitted on December 04, 2013 at 11:38:53 am EDT. Your test-CERT Incident ID number is: </div>
            <div class="spacer-vertical"></div>
            <div class="bold left-indent">2013-testCERTv36LBQB</div>
            <div class="spacer-vertical"></div>
          </div>
```

The value **2013-testCERTv36LBQB** I want it to set based upon response from server. I can do it under .ajax but can I also use javascript to append this value for me?

I will appreciate if someone can help me define execution flow.

**HTML**

```
<div id="frm">  
<form name="frm" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="Update" id="update" value="Update" />
</form>
</div>  

<!-- <div id="region-content" class="grid-12 region region-content">
  <div class="region-inner region-content-inner">
    <a id="main-content"></a>
                <h1 id="page-title" class="title">Thank you for your incident submission.</h1>
                        <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system block-main block-system-main odd block-without-title">
  <div class="block-inner clearfix">

    <div class="content clearfix">

          <div id="package-header-message">
            <div class="spacer-vertical"></div>
            <div>Your incident was submitted on December 04, 2013 at 11:38:53 am EDT. Your test-CERT Incident ID number is: </div>
            <div class="spacer-vertical"></div>
            <div class="bold left-indent">2013-testCERTv36LBQB</div>
            <div class="spacer-vertical"></div>
          </div>                       
          <p>
            The test-CERT Watch staff may contact you based on the information submitted. If you have any questions regarding this incident or would like to provide test with any edits or changes to this information, please contact test-CERT Security Operations Center at:
            </p><ul>
              <li>Phone: +1 888-282-0870</li>
              <li>Email: <a href="mailto:soc@test.com" title="Send email to the Security Operations Center Email: soc@test-cert.gov">soc@test-cert.gov</a></li>
              <li>Web: <a href="/" title="Go back to the test-CERT Homepage">http://www.test-cert.gov/</a>.</li>
            </ul>
          <p></p>
          <p>
            Secure phone and fax are available upon request. Contact test-CERT Watch at the above phone number to coordinate.
          </p>
          <p><a title="Submit another incident report" href="/forms/report">Click here</a> to submit another incident report or you can return to the <a href="/" title="Go back to the test-CERT Homepage">test-CERT Homepage</a>.
          </p>
              </div>
  </div>
</div>      </div>
</div>-->
```

**ajax/jquery**

```
  $("#update").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&last_name=' + last_name; 
alert(dataString);
        $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "bin/process.php",  
  data: dataString,  

   success: function(data) {  
      alert("ff");
  // var ctrlArray = data.split('&'); 
 if(result.indexOf("pass") > -1)      
//alert("ff");
    $('#frm').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")  
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")  
    .hide()  
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {  
      $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");  
    });  
  }  
});  
return false;

  })
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3e46s/)**

Comment: I didnt get your question ?

Comment: Me too. So, what's your actual problem?

Comment: @BlueSmith can I add the <div id="package-header-message"> dynamically without defining it statically in code? i.e js perhaps

Comment: You want to set some value from response from server, but in your code i cant see any use of response

Comment: @shadow I missed it sorry pls see update.

Comment: You can either return the whole piece of HTML of <div id="package-header-message"> from server then append it to somewhere, OR, you can have a static placeholder, then fill it with data come from server in the ajax `success` event.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? $('<div>').attr('id', 'package-header-message').appendTo('body').

Comment: @BlueSmith that seems an option where I can see on decreasing HTML content on client-side which is quiet what I want. So i can just do the echo the html from php end. ? You got an example

Comment: This is a simple pseudo code http://jsfiddle.net/3e46s/3/. You have to echo and response HTML from PHP code.

Comment: @tewathia great so with predefined html code i can use appendTo (i.e incident id) with this function to display value? But in your code where its display variable which stores incident Id.?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you mean how to put a variable's value into your node? Do `$('<div>').attr('id', 'package-header-message').text(data.value).appendTo('body')`

Comment: @BlueSmith thanks I like the concept of place-holder hope I can get it work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be wise to set and return the date from the server as well so you get one central authority on when things happened. It's generally a good idea to package as UTC in milliseconds because this gives client-side developers a lot of options and makes things much easier to manage in regards to time-zones etc. So, let's say you've handed off the following JSON to the client-side:

```
{
    responseDate:1386181171730,
    userId:'2013-testCERTv36LBQB'
}
```

Here's how I typically handle the HTML formatting using {{}} to tokenize variables for replacement.

```
function createPhm(ajaxSuccessObject){

    var //var block

    phm =[ //array/whitespace format so we can still view/edit in an HTML-ish format
        '<div id="package-header-message">',

            '<p>Your incident was submitted on {{DATE}}. Your test-CERT Incident ID number is:</p>',

            '<span class="bold left-indent">{{USER_ID}}</span>',

         '</div>'

    ].join(''), //converted to string

    injectedValues = {
        DATE = Date( ajaxSuccessObject.date ),
        USER_ID = ajaxSuccessObject.userId
    }

    ;//end var block



    return ( injectValues( injectedValues, phm ) );
}

//broke this out for more generic handling of HTML
function injectValues(valuesObj, targetString){
    for(var x in valuesObj){

        var globalRegExMatcher = new RegExp('\\{\\{'+ x +'\\}\\}','g');

        targetString = targetString.replace( globalRegExMatcher, valuesObj[x] );
    }

    return targetString;
}
```

So your ajax success function might look like:

```
...
    success: function(jsonObj){
        $( createPhm(jsonObj) ).appendTo('#frm'); //or prependTo for putting at top
    },
...
```

Quick note: Don't use .html like you have been. That replaces all the html in the container. It's just innerHTML basically.

Also, if you have HTML that will never change, put it in your HTML file. I would normally just have an empty `<div id="package-header-message"></div>` in my HTML file and .html directly into that but wanted to keep html similar to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks Erik for the suggestion to keep time (good for auditing i know). I forgot to update that I'm using data-type : text in ajax and sending off form data to server-end using serialize function. I like the idea of just having empty div which is waiting for the data which in my case comes from server in html format i.e using place-holder concept as Blue-smith (above) has mentioned. Would this not save me the hassle of defining createPhm function?

Comment: The less the server is involved with formatting HTML, the better. Imagine a jr-level web designer needs to make changes to look and feel for the message and the server-side dev is out that day. Also, I edited to make it more generic/re-usable. Think of all the things you don't have to worry about on the server now. You can just define array "templates" and value injection objects on the client-side. It's more cleanly decoupled/flexible.

Comment: I promise you, in 6 years as a primarily client-side dev, I've run into constant snags because of HTML dependencies in places I didn't have access to.

Comment: That idea of availability never crossed my idea, its a valid concern no doubt. So following up with your approach,the same pseudocode can be used in case of ajax? basically using your function I can populate or render whatever HTML code I want (perhaps) with switch statement if there is a requirement of rendering more then one dataset (considering data,time,incident id) to be one and stored in pm array and another fieldset into another array phm? Using one function over and over is more usable option i guess

Comment: That's how I like to deal with the problem, typically. Another advantage of that array format is ease of adding additional HTML strings depending on conditions and then joining right before injection. I never found the single-quotes and commas painful enough to understand the need for templating libraries that jump through some awkward hoops for similar results.

Comment: awesome:) I will go with this approach sounds convincing enough. One more then before I start using your code as starting point is there any strict dependency if same is used when data-type is not json.

Comment: dataType determines what you get in the callback. If it's not set, it will probably assume JSON. If it's an object as text, you will need to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the static portion of the html you want to show on submit already there(or maybe in a separate template .html file), but hidden, and just populate the data you get on the success of your request. Then you can unhide it.

```
$('.left-indent').text(data.value); //where data.value, say, equals "2013-testCERTv36LBQB"
$(#package-header-message').show();
```

Comment: the correct reference would be: `$('#package-header-message').show();`